# Does Batman actually kill anyone in "The Batman"?

Tags: dc, batman, the-batman

In *The Batman* (2022) we see Batman violently beating many people during the course of the movie. Though it's implied that he practises his no kill rule in this movie (when he stopped punching the Riddler cult member in the end) does he actually kill anyone? My main doubt is only about the scene where he beats the thug at the station and the hallway massacre in the Iceberg Lounge.

Comment: https://youtu.be/mDZqqQF6-l0?t=588 - Spoiler. No

Comment: I saw a lot of people praise the film for being the first live-action film Batman not to kill (with Clooney's being considered the same character as Keaton's and Kilmer's)

Comment: I have to believe deaths resulted from that reckless car chase with the Penguin. (And Penguin wasn't even arrested after the chat!?!) 
I'd also dispute the above youtube link.  As far as I recall only the Affleck batman made the news for shooting up people unlike all previous Batmans. So Robert Pattinson is hardly notable or unique for NOT killing unlike what the video implies.

Comment: He shouldn't be called Batman, he should be called The Collateral Damage Man.

Comment: @RogueJedi who got killed by the Christian Bale version?

Comment: The deaths / "collateral damage" from the Penguin car chase were all caused by Penguin, not Batman.

Comment: @A.bakker  A lot of League of Shadows guys in that house he burnt down, Two Face, arguably Ra's.

Answer (score 2):

Robert Pattinson has been very clear in interviews that his version of Batman doesn't kill people, either intentionally *or through callous indifference*.

> "There is this rule with Batman: he must not kill. It can be
> interpreted in two ways. Either he only wants to inflict the
> appropriate punishment, or he wants to kill and his self-control
> prevents him from doing so."
>
> ...
>
> "I imagined it that way from the rehearsal of the first fight, I thought it was funnier: something in him just wanted to slit the guy's throat! I told myself that if he spends his nights chasing criminals, it is impossible that he does not take pleasure in it. He suffers and it is a desire that overwhelms him. And by dint of knocking, his mind clears, he calms down, he reaches a state close to plenitude. I'm sure in this first fight, he manages to convince himself that every guy in front of him is the one who killed his mother (Laughs.) And so that allows him to vent all his rage."
>
> <sub><sup>[Robert Pattinson Explains The Batman's No-Kill Rule](https://movieweb.com/the-batman-no-kill-rule-explained/)</sup></sub>

Admittedly, some of his actions come close to the line (the car chase with the Penguin appears to have a bodycount caused by Batman chasing him and on one occasion Batman moves out of the way of a bullet, allowing it to hit a henchman) but in each of those cases, it's not the Batman who's doing the killing directly.

Comment: but isn't he indirectly the one causing it?

Comment: @shanu - I guess. his body armour seems fairly bulletproof, but that doesn't mean that he needs to *stand there and take a bullet*.